# Why am I getting a type mismatch when I change from cells(i,column).formula = "=formula" to cells(i,column) = evaluate(formula)?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing

So here is my formula. When I use .Formula , it works fine. When I change to Evaluate or try to change it to worksheetfunction.match, it comes back with type mismatch error.

What am I missing. I change from:

```
cells(i,column).formula = "=formula" to cells(i,column) = evaluate(formula)
```

```
=IFNA(ROUND(((INDEX(Calculations!$A$1:$AA$21,MATCH("D"&"SP",Calculations!$A$1:$A$21&Calculations!$B$1:$B$21,0),MATCH('LOB File'!$A2,Calculations!$A$1:$AA$1,0))+INDEX(Calculations!$A$1:$AA$21,MATCH("F"&"SP",Calculations!$A$1:$A$21&Calculations!$B$1:$B$21,0),MATCH('LOB File'!$A2,Calculations!$A$1:$AA$1,0)))/(INDEX(Calculations!$A$1:$AA$21,MATCH("D"&"SP",Calculations!$A$1:$A$21&Calculations!$B$1:$B$21,0),MATCH("Total",Calculations!$A$1:$AA$1,0))+INDEX(Calculations!$A$1:$AA$21,MATCH("F"&"SP",Calculations!$A$1:$A$21&Calculations!$B$1:$B$21,0),MATCH("Total",Calculations!$A$1:$AA$1,0))))*$F$26,0),0)
```

Comment: What value do you get when the formula is in a worksheet cell?

Comment: That's quite a long formula... almost asking for a UDF.  Lots of repeated info.

Comment: `evaluate` runs on `ActiveSheet` if you want to run it on another sheet make sure to use `Worksheets("Sheet2").Evaluate` to specify the worksheet you want to run it. • If you still get issues please include the real code you use. See [mcve].